# Camel Quartz2 Scheduler why we need to use Cron Scheduled Route Policy?

Tags: cron, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

So I'm studying about Camel Quartz2 Scheduler. Can you help me to explain more about this scenario ? Let say I want to run the job every 5 minutes from 6:00 to 18:00 everyday, so I have to define:

```
- routeFrequency: 0 0/5 * * * ? -> this will run every 5 minutes
- routeStartTime: 0 0 6 * * ? -> this will start to run at 06:00 every day
- routeStopTime: 0 0 18 * * ? -> this will stop running at 18:00 every day
```

The question is can I use the alternative way: (without using route policy at all)

```
- routeFrequency: 0 0/5 6-18 * * ? -> This will run every 5 minutes from 6 to 18 every day
```

Please help to explain what is the benefit of using policy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So after testing few scenarios. I think I can understand the difference:

```
If you're using RoutePolicy with RouteStartTime and RouteStopTime
```

==> your route will only be started by camelContext from RouteStartTime and RouteStopTime and during active time the route will be triggered by defined cron expression (routeFrequency)

```
If you're using routeFrequency only to present start time and end time
```

==> your route have to be started all of time so that the job can run at defined time.

Hope this helpful for another